# Download multiple images from remote server with PHP (a LOT of images)

Tags: php, curl, upload, copy

I am trying to download lots of files from an external server (approx. 3700 images). These images go from 30KB to 200KB each.

When I use the `copy()` function on 1 image, it works. When I use it in a loop, all I get are 30B images (empty images files).

I tried using `copy`, `cURL`, `wget`, and `file_get_contents`. Every time, I either get a lot of empty files, or nothing at all.

Here are the codes I tried:

wget:

```
exec('wget http://mediaserver.centris.ca/media.ashx?id=ADD4B9DD110633DDDB2C5A2D10&t=pi&f=I -O SIA/8605283.jpg');
```

copy:

```
if(copy($donnees['PhotoURL'], $filetocheck)) {
  echo 'Photo '.$filetocheck.' updated<br/>';
}
```

cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = $data[PhotoURL];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = $newfile;
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Nothing seems to be working properly. Unfortunately, I don't have much choice to download all these files at once, and I need a way to make it work as soon as possible.

Thanks a lot, Antoine

Comment: They are probably blocking mass downloads like this. Try asking the administrators of the server/service.

Comment: That could make sense, but this server is made for mass downloads like this, it's a system in which I have go get the images myself, instead of them having to send them to me via FTP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this function for that and worked pretty well.

```
function saveImage($urlImage, $title){

    $fullpath = '../destination/'.$title;
    $ch = curl_init ($urlImage);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        unlink($fullpath);
    }
    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    $r = fwrite($fp, $rawdata);

    setMemoryLimit($fullpath);

    fclose($fp);

    return $r;
}
```

Combined with this other one to prevent memory overflow:

```
function setMemoryLimit($filename){
   set_time_limit(50);
   $maxMemoryUsage = 258;
   $width  = 0;
   $height = 0;
   $size   = ini_get('memory_limit');

   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
   $size = $size + floor(($width * $height * 4 * 1.5 + 1048576) / 1048576);

   if ($size > $maxMemoryUsage) $size = $maxMemoryUsage;

   ini_set('memory_limit',$size.'M');

}
```

Comment: Didn't work at first, but it seems to be working now. With the variable "fullpath", I used "/home/mls/public_html..." and that's what was wrong apparently. Thanks a lot, I'll be able to download the pictures now, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Getting them one by one might be quite slow. Consider splitting them into packs of 20-50 images and grabbing them with multiple threads. Here's the code to get you started:

```
$chs = array();
$cmh = curl_multi_init();
for ($t = 0; $t < $tc; $t++)
{
    $chs[$t] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_URL, $targets[$t]);
    curl_setopt($chs[$t], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);    
}

$running=null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($cmh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

for ($t = 0; $t < $tc; $t++)
{
    $path_to_file = 'your logic for file path';
    file_put_contents($path_to_file, curl_multi_getcontent($chs[$t]));
    curl_multi_remove_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
    curl_close($chs[$t]);
}
curl_multi_close($cmh);
```

I used that approach to grab a few millions of images recently, since one by one would take up to a month.

The amount of images you grab at once should depend on their expected size and your memory limits.