# How to download images from a single webpage using PHP

Tags: php, html, curl

I created this script to get the sources of the images from a single webpage, now, i wanted to download all those images to my server using curl.

```
<?php 
// Create DOM from URL or file
require_once 'library/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://adamkhoury.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) //every image found is declared as $element
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download multiple images from remote server with PHP (a LOT of images)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436388/download-multiple-images-from-remote-server-with-php-a-lot-of-images)

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this

```
file_put_contents("filename.extension", file_get_contents($element->src));
```

Comment: Thanks, just made a tiny revision, to the filename, But how can i add a progress bar? @slash197

Answer (score 0):

There is file_get_contents() function in PHP for getting external contents and file_put_contents() for storing content in a file...

use file_get_contents() to download images and use file_put_contents() to store that:

```
$image = file_get_contents($element->src);
file_get_contents("image.jpg",$image);
```

of course, there is another method names cURL in php for downloading external data...