# Facebook Image Import causes 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a Facebook Canvas app, one of whose features is to copy the profile pics (50x50) of max. 20 friends and paste it onto a template of 600x500 pixels. This particular feature was working fine until last week (August 13-14), when my server started showing 504 Gateway Timeout(NGINX) or 500 Internal Server Error (Apache). I tried all possible options including Rolling back code changes, Migrating to different server, increasing timeout in PHP.ini, using FQL instead of Graph API, but none helped in fixing this Timeout issue.

Recently, I realized that the app fails at the point of exectuion of **imagecreatefromstring/jpeg/png/gif** functions with Facebook image URL (https://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture or *Path to Facebook CDN*) as argument. However I noted (and confirmed by testing) that the app fails only when more than one calls are made by above functions to a Facebook Image URL. I tried using CURL as well as [Curl Multi Exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). I also tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436388/download-multiple-images-from-remote-server-with-php-a-lot-of-images), but the Timeout is still happening. I appended a **User_Agent** String to my requests to Facebook, but that too didnot work.

Two more things I noted.

1. The problem occurs with images of Facebook/FBCDN domain only. Similar requests  remote images on several other domains **did not throw** any timeout.
2. Despite throwing timeout, images get copied in almost 50% of cases.

Have you faced similar problem before? Any idea what went wrong or did Facebook implement any Image Download Policy recently?

I shall be thankful, if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using cURL, you need to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` so it correctly forwards the request to the CDN location of the image. The below example demonstrates how works:

```
header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/60506094/picture';

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 ); 

$resp = curl_exec( $curl );

curl_close( $curl );

echo $resp;
```

You can then pass `$resp` into the `imagecreatefromstring` function.

Comment: Hi Niraj, I tried running above code but it gave 504 Gateway Timeout. The problem happens even when using direct url of Facebook CDN.

Comment: Don't use direct CDN urls as they are likely to change when the user updates their profile. You should access the profile image as above.